# Эмуляция нажатий клавиш клавиатуры на Python 3 под Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, клавиатура

Каким образом можно симулировать нажатия клавиш клавиатуры, чтобы, например, запустив соответствующий скрипт, заданный текст сам набирался в сторонней программе? Однако больше интересует эмуляция сочетания клавиш, причем не символьных или цифирных, а таких как CTRL или SHIFT. Кроссплатформенность не важна.

Comment: Существовал SendKeys модуль, который легко позволял специальные клавиши использовать. Не знаю, работает ли на Python 3. Вот [пример использования (в конце ответа](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12606327/4279).

Comment: Проблема в том, что через pip3 install sendkeys он не устанавливается, падает с ошибками, никак не исключёнными!

Comment: вполне вероятно. Модуль древний и главное его (варианта) достоинство было это простота и отсутствие зависимостей кроме ctypes (не могу сейчас исходник найти, вот [пример как он мог выглядеть](https://bitbucket.org/markm/sendkeysctypes/src/68b60cd364e9d890c097a3927d2e2617e2784dda/SendKeysCtypes.py)). pywinauto менее простой модуль, который также `SendInput()` API использует. Единственный недостаток pyautogui по сравнению с SendKeys, то что pillow является зависимостью, а так одни плюсы: также простой, но переносимый, поддерживает не только клавиши.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Помог модуль pyautogui (немного о нём [здесь](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter18/)). К сожалению не поддерживает кириллицу, но в моём случае сие проблемой не является.