# Как из скрипта python передать в запущенную командную строку текст?

Tags: python, cmd

Через скрипт питона запускаю exe-файл, который выполняется в консоли и по окончанию работы спрашивает пользователя "Продолжить (y - да, n - нет)"

Как мне через скрипт питона уже в запущенную консоль ввести текст? например в моем случае символы - y или n?

Comment: Связанный вопрос [Эмуляция нажатий клавиш клавиатуры на Python 3 под Windows](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/615379/23044)

Comment: Связанный вопрос [Запустить дочерний процесс и овладеть его потоками I/O](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/604773/23044)

Answer (score 3):

С помощью `subprocess.Popen`, можно так:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

process = Popen(['app.exe'], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
stdout_data = process.communicate(input='y')[0]
```

Если вам необходимо дождаться окончания работы, а затем написать y/n, то перед `communicate` добавьте этот цикл:

```
while True:
    line = process.stdout.readline()
    if line == '':
        break
```

Comment: Если процесс ожидает ввода прямо с консоли, то `stdin=PIPE` подход не будет работать. По мелочи: 1- упомяните версию Питона (к примеру, код как написан не будет на Питоне 3 работать из-за str vs. bytes разницы) 2- перехватывать вывод не обязательно (не вижу где это в вопросе указано) 3- `while True` цикл может никогда не закончится, если процесс явно свой stdout не закрывает, прежде чем ожидать ввод на stdin (вероятно что не закрывает) 4- можно попробовать: `subprocess.run("app.exe", input=b"y")`