# Считывание данных из текстового поля Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как получить, удалить и вставить текст из любого текстового поля посредством Python'a? То есть, совсем из любого. Будь то, текстовое поле меседжера, или форма HTML на сайте.

Windows 10/Python 3.6.1

Comment: Связанный вопрос [Эмуляция нажатий клавиш клавиатуры на Python 3 под Windows](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/615379/%D0%AD%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%88-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%B0-python-3-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4-windows)

Comment: @jfs то есть, эмулировать нажатие CTRL + A итд?

Comment: Если неизвестно как текстовое роле реализовано, то кроме как ввод эмулировать (мышка, клавиатура) ничего другого и не остаётся.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. Самым логичным способом будет выделить весь текст , вырезать в буфер обмена ([тут рассказано как сделать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/657733/%D0%98%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-ctrla-ctrlx-ctrlv-python)) и уже из программы (посредством модуля tkinter) вытащить строку.

Comment: Не вижу никакой связи между WScript.Shell SendKeys и tkinter. Как код из ссылки можно применить для текущего вопроса, лучше прямо в ответе указать (если вопросы не дубликаты, если вы из считаете дубликатами, тогда вместо ответа ссылки, просто попросите закрыть ваш вопрос как дубликат — чтобы полезные ответы в одном месте собирать).

Comment: @jfs WScript.Shell - имитирует нажатия клавиш. tkinter - вытаскивает данные из буфера. Всё.
Есть рабочий код.