# Имитация нажатия Ctrl+A, Ctrl+X, Ctrl+V Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Необходимо сделать имитацию нажатия клавиш <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> и <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>. Пробовал сделать вот так:

```
import win32com.client

shell = win32com.client.Dispatch('WScript.Shell')
shell.SendKeys('^A')
shell.SendKeys('^X')
# Кое-какие действия с буфером обмена 
shell.SendKeys('^V')
```

Не получается. Причём, комбинации типа '+%', 'A' и т.д. работают прекрасно. Буду премного благодарен за название модуля, от которого стоит отталкиваться.

Windows 10/Python 3.6.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Разобрался. Прописывая `shell.SendKeys('^A')` необходимо использовать НИЖНИЙ РЕГИСТР. То есть: `shell.SendKeys('^a')`. Тогда сработает.